# Getting "undefined method `flash`" for my controllers after updating Rails from 4.1 to 5.2 and added the responders gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, applicationcontroller, respond-with, responders

I'm in the process of updating rails from 4.1 to 5.2
I added the `responders` gem so respond_with is present.
My ApplicationController now looks like this:

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  self.responder = ApplicationResponder
  respond_to :html`

However, when I call `respond_with` I get this error:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `flash' for #<MyController>
```

I noticed in the responders README that there is a flash responder, however I do not want to use that.

Comment: Adding this method to the controller fixed the issue
`def flash
    {}
  end`

Comment: The above gets the code to run, but I cannot render html now, only json

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to "config/environments/production.rb"

**config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash**